# Error 3131 when trying to query on multiselect list box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MultiSelect List Box that I'm trying to use as criteria in a query. I'm fine until the line of code "qdf.SQL = strSQL" at which point I receive the error code 3131.  If I place a message box just after the "strSQL =" command, it appears to populate with the correct data.

I am pulling from a list of Categories on a form (Forms("frmMain").listCat1).

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub CAT1_Criteria()

Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strCAT1 As String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim strSQL As String

Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set ctl = Forms("frmMain").listCat1

For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
strCAT1 = strCAT1 & ",'" & ctl.ItemData(varItem) _
& "'"
Next varItem

If Len(strCAT1) = 0 Then
strCAT1 = "Like '*'"
Else
strCAT1 = Right(strCAT1, Len(strCAT1) - 1)
strCAT1 = "IN(" & strCAT1 & ")"
End If

strSQL = "SELECT dbo_CATEGORY1.* FROM dbo_CATEGORY1" & _
      "WHERE dbo_CATEGORY1.[LEVEL1] " & strCAT1 & ";"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryCAT1_Sel")
qdf.SQL = strSQL

'Set qdf = Nothing
'Set db = Nothing

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryCAT1_Sel"

End Sub
```

Comment: This has been resolved.

I changed this:

    strSQL = "SELECT dbo_CATEGORY1.* FROM  dbo_CATEGORY1" & _
      "WHERE dbo_CATEGORY1.[LEVEL1] " & strCAT1 & ";"

to this:

    strSQL = "SELECT dbo_CATEGORY1.* FROM dbo_CATEGORY1" & Chr(13) & "WHERE dbo_CATEGORY1.[LEVEL1] " & strCAT1 & ";"

Comment: Glad you solved this, but from the looks of things, all you needed was a space; `"SELECT dbo_CATEGORY1.* FROM dbo_CATEGORY1" & _
      "WHERE dbo_CATEGORY1.[LEVEL1] " & strCAT1 & ";"` reads as "SELECT dbo_CATEGORY1.* FROM dbo_CATEGORY1WHERE dbo_CATEGORY1.[LEVEL1] Like '*'". So unless your table is called `dbo_CATEGORY1WHERE` you'd have a problem. Just changing this portion from `FROM dbo_CATEGORY1" & _` to `FROM dbo_CATEGORY1 " & _` should have solved the issue.

Comment: Yup.  That would have worked too.  Thanks for the input.